# Enter data to particular column in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a text box that retrieve email from membership table in database. User may edit their email and update the new email. My question is, how to replace the old email with the new one? What is the query for sql?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into aspnet_membership("i dont know how whether to write all columns or only email);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Textbox2.Text);
```

Comment: Your question should be..How do i Update records instead of entering Data according to your question's content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
You may need UserId, and new Email to replace existing email address for the given existing user.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_membership SET email = @newEmail WHERE UserID = @userID");

cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Textbox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues("@UserId", YourUserId);

conn.open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.close();
```

Comment: There may be many ways, it depends on your solution. If a user is editing his info, then he might be loggdin, then put users UserId into session at login logic. So while updating email you may have UserId in session. If administrator is changing the email then create a listing of users. By clicking on users name, it shows users edit form and store UserId in hidden field, so on submit it would be available.

Comment: when i make session for userid protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     Session["id"] = Login1.UserId;
    } it gives me error: does not contain a definition for userid

Comment: Use this: int UserId = (int)Session["id"]; And on above code change this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues("@UserId", UserId); Note: I have guessed that UserId is in int.

Comment: Guid UserId = new Guid(Session["id"].ToString());

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, how to replace the old email with the new one?

You need an `UPDATE` in this case, instead of an `INSERT`:

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_membership SET 
          email = @email WHERE userID = @userID", conn);
```

Comment: how to get userID? Should make a session to hold user id?

Comment: Yes, that is the common solution for this, but don't you have already a solution to identify and keep some info about the logged in user or something?

Comment: I only make a session that hold username during login session. How to make id session since the aspnet_membership doesnt have a username colum

Answer (score 2):

It will work like any other simple update SQL Query:

```
update TableName set Columname = @Value where Username = @Value
```

Comment: +1 , since you were the first one with update idea, you may put some effort in code formatting, see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use update query and not insert query.

see syntax here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

check this link from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

SELECT REPLACE('abcdefghicde','cde','xxx');
GO

Answer (score 0):

As you want to `Update` EmailID so your query should be

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update aspnet_membership set email=@email where  UserID=@UserID");
```

This should work for you, because your `Insert`query which you are trying, this will always insert a new record instead of updating older records..